# how to save image locally in react-native after fetching it from the server?

Tags: react-native

I have to download weather condition image from the server. The same image can be used for multiple places. So, I should not download the same image again and again from the server. Once I download an image, store it locally and re-use it next time if some other place require the same image.

This is my requirement. How to do this for both android and ios?

Comment: You need to cache the image in the local file system. Take a look at this library,
https://github.com/wagslane/react-native-expo-cached-image

Comment: How to do it in bare react-native project?